# What is an efficient heap implementation for an allocation subsystem?

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures, game-engine

Let's say I want to write a 3D game engine - somewhere along the lines of DOOM and Quake. And I want to do it in pure C (not sure if that's relevant, but just in case...).

The first thing worth tackling I think would be the engines memory allocation. I've looked at some source code for this (Quake 3, DOOM 3), and in terms of allocation management, I've found that a B-tree seems like a good way to go, but I'm not sure if that would

A binary heap would be simpler, but from what I've read I'm not sure it would scale well. Maybe I'm wrong?

Ideally, I'm looking for something between O(1) and O(n log n) runtime efficiency. I'm not sure if this is realistic o
not though :)

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing the heap data structure, which is an implementation of the priority queue ADT, and "the heap" or free store, a memory region and associated metadata for dynamic memory allocation? The two are completely separate things (I've never heard of anyone mixing the two successfully). If you don't confuse the two, could you explain *what* you'd use a binary heap or B-tree for, i.e. what you'd store on it and how that relates to memory allocation? And finally, why do you think you need to roll your own general purpose allocator, before you've even written anything else?

Comment: No, the first thing worth tackling is making the engine work: making sure that it draws what it's supposed to draw where it's supposed to be drawn. The memory allocator is an optimization that you can put off for a very long time and possibly won't even have to do. Make it work. Then profile it. Then optimize those things that are bottlenecks. It's highly unlikely that the memory allocator will be the major bottleneck, so it makes no sense to optimize it first.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to start you can simply use the regular malloc provided by your compiler/build environment. Then, once your engine will look great, you could attempt to write your own memory allocator.

Doom 3 offer both options (enabled at compile time): either it uses an internal memory allocator (this is the default), or can use the regular malloc.

You can have a look at Heap.cpp in Doom 3 source code. It is based on BTrees. But honestly, you'll probably find this very difficult to understand !